# MongoDB $size function to filter multiple values

Tags: mongodb

Here's my collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": string
    },
    "movie_id": int,
    "director": string,
    "release_year": int,
    "ratings": int,
    "movie_name": string,
    "country": string,
    "genre": string,
    "actors": [int],
    "company": {
        "name": string,
        "start_year": int,
        "country": string
    }
}
```

I need to return the movie names of movies that have 1,3,5, or 7 cast members (actors). The array "actors" contains the ID numbers of the actors for each movie. Using the $size function on actors array will give me the size, but how can I filter by condition that the size is 1,3,5 or 7?

I read the documentation on $size, it cannot do what I need. It seems to recommend creating a new field for this count. How do I do this? I'm new to MongoDB and did not have success creating a new field using $size.

Here is my attempt so far: It only filters by a fixed size, like 5.

```
db.Movies.find({ratings: {$gt: 6}, actors: { $size: 5}},
{_id: 0, movie_name:1})
```

Comment: did you try using `$or` to check for different sizes?  Note that this type of query is not indexable, so it will have to read every movie from the database in order to count the number of actors.

Comment: yeah I tried $or and got it to work finally.